# Parse PhoneGap Facebook Authentication for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, parse-platform, phonegap-build

I currently have an app that I built using the [online PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) feature.
I have entered the necessary keys, downloaded the .ipa, and have the app running on my phone that I installed via iTunes. 
Everything works fine except I am present with the following error every time I try to authenticate with facebook in the app:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.:
>       One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
>       It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain 
>       must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I have done a bit of research and tried several suggestions, including changing my App URL on the facebook developer page to: http://localhost.com/, but nothing seemed to work.

I stumbled on a couple articles suggesting that I change some things in the `config.xml` but since I packaged this app with the PhoneGap build, I am not sure where that is located/how to access it.

**Note:** My facebook authentication was done with the [Parse API](http://www.parse.com), here is the code:

```
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxx', // Facebook App ID
          cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
          xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
          version    : 'v2.4' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
        });
      };


      (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", { ... }
```

Comment: What is your target version `iOS7`, `iOS8` or `iOS9`? What is your compiler target `3.7.0`, `cli-5.1.1` or `cli-5.2.0`? Have you applied the `whitelist` and the `CSP`?

Comment: Back in the day I remember I had this same issue. What I ended up doing was to load a remote endpoint on my phonegap app, which of course, had a valid FB redirect URL. This might not be the best option for you, but just letting you know.

Comment: Hey @corvuszero, thanks for the reply! Would you mind specifying how you loaded a remote endpoint? I'm not exactly sure how to do that